# Mac Magic Mouse & Touchpad Drag But Won't Drop

Tags: mac, touchpad, drag-and-drop, magic-mouse

I have a MacBookPro, with a Magic Mouse attached. Suddenly, I'm not able to drag and drop using either device.

I can select an item and drag it, but not drop it anywhere. I eventually have to hit escape, and then the object returns to its original position.

Also, this problem is not limited to the Finder. PS, Transmit, Mail, and a host of other apps all demonstrate the same behavior.

So far, I've:

Zapped the PRAM.
Repaired Hard Drive and Permissions (no problems found).
Trashed the mouse preferences.

Thoughts?

Comment: One of the possible workarounds: Mouse Keys. Apple > System Preferences... > System > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad. After enabling Mouse Keys to start with 5 presses of Option, you can do that, then press keypad 5 (if a full keyboard is attached) or letter i (if you are using the MacBook Pro built-in keyboard) to drop during a drag. Sounds like a "drag", but it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the MacBook to sleep, and then waking it back up, seems to *temporarily* solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, no real solution. I reinstalled Mountain Lion, repaired disk permissions, pram reset, all the other standard this is a mac problem stuff. 
nothing. 
for me though, it only stops dragging after some unspecified amount of time or when i put mac to sleep. 
super annoying. any updates?